# Proof about homeomorphic map. Do I have to consider relative phase?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

$X \subset \mathbb{R}$ : compact set

$f$ : $X \to [0,1] \ $ $\big($ $[0,1]$ is closed interval $\big)$

$f$ is continuous and bijective.

Then, is $f$ homeomorphic map? i.e. is $f^{-1}$ continuous?

My attempt is as following.

Let $F \subset X$ closed set.

Since $X$ is compact, $F$ is also compact.

Since $F$ is compact and $f$ is conti, $(f^{-1})^{-1} (F)=f(F)$ is compact.

If I can say $[0,1]$ is hausdorff, $(f^{-1})^{-1} (F)=f(F)$ is closed since compact set in hausdorff space is closed.

But I'm not sure of this idea.
Because domain of $f^{-1}$ is $[0,1]$, I may have to consider not $[0,1]$ but relative phase $([0,1], \mathscr{O}_{[0,1]})$, where $\mathscr{O}_{[0,1]}=\{ U \cap [0,1] | U \in \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{R}} \}.$

I think $([0,1], \mathscr{O}_{[0,1]})$ is hausdorff.

Visually, $\forall a, b \in [0,1] \ (a<b)$ can be separated by $U,V \in \mathscr{O}_{[0,1]}$, where $U$ is intersection of certain open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and $[0,1]$,  $V$ is intersection of certain open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and $[0,1]$, $a\in U, b\in V$, and $U\cap V =\phi.$

Is my idea correct? Or is $([0,1], \mathscr{O}_{[0,1]})$ not hausdorff?

Can I conclude that $(f^{-1})^{-1}(F)$ is closed?

Comment: Yes. Every subspace of Hausdorff space is Hausdorff.

Comment: On a side note, the usual terminology is that $f$ is a *homeomorphism*, and then $X$ and $[0,1]$ are *homeomorphic spaces*. The saying "homeomorphic map" can be confusing.